# How does a Read on Write snapshot handle modifications/deletions?

Tags: snapshot

A read on write snapshot will cause any changes/updates to be redirected to new blocks. It's easy to see how this can work if data is to be appended, but what if data in the block is modified or deleted? Since the snapshotted block can't be modified, how is the information of what is modified or deleted applied? It can't be just metadata from here on out, right? That would really slow things down if the data is to be used for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you use layered filesystem. Each snapshot create a new layer, and when you ask for a file metadata / a file data, you query the top layer which will delegate to lower layer if there is no data about the query in the current layer.

When you delete a file, you simply put in top layer file xxx is deleted.
  when you modify a block you create the new block on top layer with metadata referencing one block in new layer, delegating other to lower layer.

It is like docker works, and to go a little bit deeper you can check those link for instance :

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#how-container-reads-and-writes-work-with-overlay-or-overlay2

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/#how-the-btrfs-storage-driver-works